# Analyzer 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers.FunctionAnalyzer' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, azure-functions, roslyn-code-analysis

I get this warning while building my Azure functions project. There aren't much details in the the stack trace. Can anyone please help me make sense of this error?

```
> CSC : warning AD0001: Analyzer
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers.FunctionAnalyzer'
> threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' with
> message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.
```

Here's the stacktrace if it helps:

```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Detail
> Description Warning   AD0001  Analyzer
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers.FunctionAnalyzer'
> threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' with
> message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.'. 
        1   Active  Analyzer
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers.FunctionAnalyzer'
> threw the following exception: 'Exception occurred with following
> context: Compilation: 
> 
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object.    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers.ArgumentAnalyzer.TryGetInputFromDurableContextCall(SemanticModel
> semanticModel, SyntaxNode definitionInput, SyntaxNode&
> inputFromContext)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers.ArgumentAnalyzer.TryGetDefinitionInputType(SemanticModel
> semanticModel, ActivityFunctionDefinition functionDefinition,
> ITypeSymbol& definitionInputType)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers.ArgumentAnalyzer.ReportProblems(CompilationAnalysisContext
> context, SemanticModel semanticModel, IEnumerable`1
> availableFunctions, IEnumerable`1 calledFunctions)    at
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers.FunctionAnalyzer.RegisterAnalyzers(CompilationAnalysisContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor.<>c.<ExecuteCompilationActionsCore>b__46_1(ValueTuple`2
> data)    at
> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerExecutor.ExecuteAndCatchIfThrows_NoLock[TArg](DiagnosticAnalyzer
> analyzer, Action`1 analyze, TArg argument, Nullable`1 info)
> ----- '.
```

Comment: Can you offer the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot. Any steps to help debug this problem would work too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DurableTask Analyzer is a Roslyn analyzer that checks your code for inconsistencies when working with Durable Functions to help you prevent common mistakes. It is part of the DurableFunctions extension now.

Are you using the latest version of Durable Functions, [v2.2.1](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/releases/tag/v2.2.1)?
This version contains the most recent version of the DurableTask Analyzer v0.2.1 as a dependency and it appears there is a bug in there which causes the exception.

You could remove the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers` dependency as a workaround to avoid getting this exception as follows:

- Go to your local folder where the DurableTask package is stored. For me this is: `C:\Users\%User%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.webjobs.extensions.durabletask\2.2.1`
- Open the `nuspec` file and comment out (or remove) the two dependencies for `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers`, one for `.NETFramework4.6.1`, and one for `.NETStandard2.0`.
- Save the nuspec
- In your IDE, remove the package reference to the DurableTask extension.
- Add the DurableTask extension again. Since the package it's still in your local folder it should not download it from nuget.org. It will load the extension but not with the Analyzer now. It's hacky but it works.

I get the same error as you btw. I will check the issues at [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues) and will add a new one there if it hasn't been done yet.

Update: [GH issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1320) has been created.

Comment: Thanks for the response Marc! Can you please educate me on how to remove the analyzer dependency since it comes as a part of the 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask' nuget package?

Comment: I've updated my answer, to clarify the procedure. I'm also seeing the same issue now, using the latest version of the Analyzer.

Comment: I've submitted an issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/1320. My error is slightly different than yours so perhaps you could add your specific repro steps to this issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for the details Marc! I tried reproducing the same issue with identical code in a fresh project and was unable to repro it. So, I think the issue is resolved for me now, but it was good to know about how to disable the analyzer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that! :) Could you please accept my answer then?

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the latest [DurableTask.Analyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.Analyzers/) package (v0.3.0) to my project in order to resolve this issue.

Currently [DurableTask](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/) package (v2.2.2) still uses DurableTask.Analyzers v0.2.3 which raises warnings on build